# What is a natual expression for "vast collection"?

Tags: words

I can't seen to find a natural expression for "vast collection", as in:

> I have a vast collection of baseball cards.

Literally there is 莫大なコレクション, but that seems pretty unnatural and I don't see it used online much. I know there are other adjectives like 巨大 or 大規模, but I can't find a good combination. Also, I am not sure if 集まり would be better than コレクション or if there is another common word pairing here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [膨大]{ぼうだい}なコレクション?
(And I thought of [収集]{しゅうしゅう} for "collection", but 「膨大な収集」 doesn't sound good...)

> I have vast collection of baseball cards.

Your sentence would (rather literally) translate to:

> (私は)野球カードの膨大なコレクションを持っています / 所有しています。

Note that this sounds quite formal, and maybe a bit literary or stiff.

If you're looking for an expression that would be used in normal/daily conversation, how about:

> (私は)野球カードをたくさん/いっぱい集めています。
>   (私は)野球カードをたくさん/いっぱいコレクションしています。

Comment: I've definitely heard 「膨大なコレクション」before. A quoted google search shows almost 300k hits for "膨大なコレクション".

Comment: Just as a suggestion for emphasis, you could also write 「多岐に渡る膨大なコレクション」.

Comment: @sazarando: Google hits are misleading. Try actually going to the later pages and you'll see that there are only 176 results on 18 pages. I have no idea why it works like that but basically you can't trust the first number you see, you always need to dig a bit deeper. Well, 176 hits is still a decent count I guess.